# how do i get geany to run python 2.7.3 not python version 3

Tags: python

whenever i make a program on geany and with python and use the pygame module and run it it returns with an error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 1, in 
    import time,pygane
ImportError: No module named pygane

i heard that if you run python 2.7.3 on geany it recognizes the pygame module

Comment: `pygame` is not `pygane` - perhaps that's an additional issue.

Comment: Did you [configure geany](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094105/how-can-i-configure-geany-to-compile-and-run-my-python-programs) to run python scripts? Did enable the [universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)? Did you install `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`?

Answer (score 2):

Either configure Geany inside build menu -> Set build commands hard to use Python 2.7 by choosing python2 (is this supported by Ubuntu?) or adjust your shebang of your Python files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Geany by default uses Python 3 to run the Python codes. So in order to run Python 2 codes, do the following.

**Step 1:** Go to Build -> Set build commands in the menu bar (screenshot attached below).

[Build -> Set Build Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWUsd.png)

**Step 2:** You would get a "Set Build Commands" window like this:

[Set Build Commands window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAQdP.png)

You can clearly see the "Compile" and "Execute" build commands as `python3 -m py_compile "%f"` and `python3 "%f"` respectively.

**Step 3:** In both of these commands, change `python3` to `python` and you are good to go. Doing this directs Geany to call `python` instead of `python3`:

[New Build Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFjnO.png)

And make sure before doing all these, save the code with a `.py` extension!